# php contact form works but doesn't look right

Tags: php, html, css

continuing my development of my first real site, I have again come to another road block.

I am trying to get a contact form working on my site, and after lots of research I was able to get the form to accept input, validate, show errors for empty "required fields" and then echo the inputted data, with intent to later remove the echo and have that data emailed. so far so good, but I'm tired of working on that right now, so for now I'm trying to get the page to look like the others (navbar, font, etc).

my folder structure is like this(simplified):

```
Project
 [bootstrap]
   -[css]
   -[fonts]
   -[js]
 [css]
   -HStyles.css
   -EStyles.css
   -CStyles.css
 [fa] (font awesome)
 [img]
   -1.jpg
  - 2.jpg
 [php]
   -get_post.php(contact page) 
 home.html
 events.html
```

If I strip the php code from my get_post.php file and rename the extension to .html, everything looks the way it should, though the page is static.
here is my php code

```
<?php
     define( "TITLE", "POST"); 

if( isset( $_POST["submit"])) {
function validateFormData($_formData) {

$formData = trim (stripslashes (htmlspecialchars($formData)));
return $formData;
}

if (!$_POST["name"]) {
    $nameError = "Required Field";
}
else {
$name = validateFormData( $_POST["name"]);
}

    if (!$_POST["lname"]) {
    $nameError = "Required Field";
}
else {
$name = validateFormData( $_POST["lname"]);
}

if (!$_POST["email"]) {
    $emailError = "Required Field";
}
else {
    $email = validateFormData( $_POST["email"]);
    }
}

if (!$_POST["phone"]) {
    $nameError = "Required Field";
}
else {
$name = validateFormData( $_POST["phone"]);
}

if (!$_POST["message"]) {
    $nameError = "Required Field";
}
else {
$name = validateFormData( $_POST["message"]);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">


    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="..//fa\css\font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <title>
            The Friendly Medium
        </title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/CStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="content">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">



                                <li>
                                    <a href="../home.html">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="glass" href="../events.html">Events</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a class="glass" href="../private-readings.html">Private Readings</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="glass" href="../testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a class="glass" href="get_post.php">Contact Us</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="navsocial">
                                <ul class="navbar-right social">
                                    <li><a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/DawnCFriendly/?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/dfriendlymedium"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>


                <section class="contact">
                    <div class="container"></div>
                    <p>Please fill out the form below</p>
                    <h5 class="text-danger">* Reqired Field</h5>


                    <div class="container">

                        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ); ?>" method="post">

                            <small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $nameError; ?></small>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name*">

                            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name">
                            <small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $emailError; ?></small>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email*">

                            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone">
                            <small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $nameError; ?></small>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="8" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit">


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </section>



                <?php

            if( isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                echo "your info <br>"; 
               echo $_POST["name"];
                 }
            ?><br>
                <?php

            if( isset($_POST["submit"])) {                
               echo $_POST["lname"];
                 }
            ?><br>
                <?php

            if( isset($_POST["submit"])) {                
               echo $_POST["email"];
                 }
            ?><br>

               <?php

            if( isset($_POST["submit"])) {                
               echo $_POST["phone"];
                 }
            ?><br>
                <?php

            if( isset($_POST["submit"])) {                
               echo $_POST["message"];
                 }
            ?>


            </div>



            <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js "></script>
            <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
            <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
        </div>
            </body>

    </html>
```

and here is my css

```
    html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    /* Height of the footer element */
}

nav.navbar-inverse {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.9) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all ease .2s;
    transition: all ease .2s;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    text-shadow: 1.3px 1px #222;
    background-color: #4da7ff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    text-shadow: 1.3px 1px #222;
    background-color: #4da7ff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: black;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-nav >li {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.navbar-nav >li {
    background: none;
    border-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1 14px #222;
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px #222;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: rgba(65, 70, 70, 0.9);
}

.social {
    padding: 0px;
}

.navsocial ul {
    margin-top: -55px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.navsocial i {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.navsocial ul li {
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.facebook {
    color: #4060A5;
}

.twitter {
    color: #00ABE3;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all ease .2s;
    transition: all ease .2s;
    color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
    color: #00ABE3;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all ease .2s;
    transition: all ease .2s;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -50px;
}

.contact p {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.contact h5 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: -130px;
}

form {
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 140px auto 100px;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 7px;
    border: solid 1px #888;
    margin: 0 0 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}

.form-control message {
    font-size: 10px;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    background: #222;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: calibri, Times, serif;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 568px) {
    .cover h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    section {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .newsletter {
        padding-top: 64px;
    }
    .newsletter p {
        margin-bottom: 75px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 768px) {
    .about p {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 75px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .navsocial i {
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding-top: 11px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 991px) {
    .about p {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 100px;
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 1025px) {
    .about p {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 1150px) {
    .about p {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 1400px) {
    .about p {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-right: 300px;
        margin-left: 300px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 991px) {
    .navsocial i {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-collapse li {
        font-size: 20px;

    }
    .navbar-nav >li {
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: whitesmoke;
    }
    @media only screen and ( max-width: 900px) {
        nav.navbar-inverse {
            margin-left: -50px;
        }
    }
```

obviously I'm doing something wrong, likely many things but lets just start with getting the page to look like my html pages. Maybe someone can provide a better way of approaching this?

I also want to thank everyone in advance for their help! This is such a great community and I'm happy to be here :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not modified your bootstrap links to reflect the path of the `.php` file as opposed to the `.html` files.

I.e.

```
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

rather than

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

(Same with the `bootstrap.min.js` link further down)

Additionally your "Font Awesome" link seems a bit off:

```
<link href="..//fa\css\font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

should be

```
<link href="../fa/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Correcting this might fix your problems. Before doing this however, i would consider if there was any good reason for keeping the php-file in a separate folder? If you have a good reason i guess that's fine, but it seems like an unnecessary complication.

An additional note: Assuming you have internet available when working on this: the bootstrap and Font Awesome files are available through fast, reliable content delivery networks (e.g. `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`), and using these would make your local, relative links unnecessary. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you that worked! can't believe I missed that, I guess long hours staring at code will do that. I also moved the php file out to the root. 



The reason it was in there in the first place was because when I started creating the site, I hadn't yet learned any php so I treated it like my css and img folders, and grouped file types that way, while the contact page  was designed in an html file which now is not needed.

Comment: Live and learn! :) Mistakes like that are easily made and easily missed!